# Change the Drupal Commerce checkout completion page

Tags: 7, commerce

How do I redirect the final checkout page of my Drupal Commerce install (from `checkout/%/complete`) to the actual order created (`user/%/order/%`)?

This seems easier than having to build and theme the line items in the completion message pane, not to mention I have inserted other information to the order display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Rules module to redirect on checkout completion event, and this seems to be working so far.